# PF transfer taxed under 194A India

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction, accounting

I have changed my job (previously TCS) in August 2015.

I Transferred my PF in May 2016. As far I know PF is not taxable. But in my Form 26AS I see 800(10% of interest accumulated from September 2015 to March 2016) rupees deducted by TCS PF trust under 194A section.

Picture http://oi67.tinypic.com/2irt9cl.jpg .

1. Is the deduction correct against PF interest?
2. If so,In ITR 1 where should I declare this interest?
3. Is it under Income from Other Sources (Ensure to fill Sch TDS2).
4. What about 80TTA for this interest?

Comment: Image link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

> I Transferred my PF in May 2016. As far I know PF is not taxable.

Yes if you have transferred your PF then its not taxable.

> But in my Form 26AS i see 800(10% of interest accumulated from September 2015 to March 2016) rupees deducted by TCS PF trust under 194A section.

Can you check with your employer that they have processed this as Transfer. Generally large companies run private trust and if they don't receive the Transfer instructions within 3 months of leaving, they treat this as withdrawl and act accordingly.

> If so,In ITR 1 where should i declare this interest? Is it under Income from Other Sources (Ensure to fill Sch TDS2).

Yes this needs to be declared as income from other sources. As much as I know this can't be claimed under 80TTA. 80TTA is only applicable on interest in savings bank.